# What does this warning "pointer to a function used in arithmetic" mean?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <vector> 
class myClass
{
public:
  static std::vector<int> race(int v1, int v2, int v3);
  static int the_v1 = race[0];
  static int the_v2 = race[1];
  static int the_v3 = race[2]; 
}

int main() {}
```

I receive an error saying:

> Warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic

at lines 6, 7, and 8. I am confused why I receive this error and I am also confused why it refers to `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` as functions.

Comment: I'm curious what you're trying to achieve with this snippet.

Comment: What is this code trying to accomplish exactly? Please clarify.

Comment: Weird code, presumably you meant `race` to be a vector of size 3. But if you did then where are you giving it any particular values? And why would you want to copy those values to three integer variables? Explain what you are actually trying to do and someone will show you the correct syntax.

Answer (score 7):

This declaration:

```
static std::vector<int> race(int v1, int v2, int v3);
```

declares `race` to be a `static` member function that takes 3 `int` parameters and returns a `std::vector<int>`.

When you write `race[0]` the function `race` decays to a function pointer, and then you're indexing into that. The compiler is warning you that this never makes sense, which is true.

Note that you're only getting a *warning* instead of an *error* because you're presumably compiling the code with GCC, which accepts this code as an extension. As far as the language is concerned, this is not allowed, and is an error.

Also, the compiler is not referring to `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` as functions, it's only referring to `race` as a function, which is also true.

Comment: Function pointer arithmetic is just not allowed by the standard, only [as a GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html). The compiler is warning that this is non-standard (But as a GNU extension, `race[0] == *race`, and other indices might make sense when working with raw code)

Comment: @Artyer That's a very good point, thank you. I've added that clarification to the answer as well, though I've skipped the part about *why* gcc provides this particular extension.